# "I want you to know how much your effort, time, and work {are/is} appreciated."

Tags: grammatical-number, verb-agreement, coordinating-conjunctions

What kind of verb we should use after some uncountable nouns separated by commas as the subject of our sentence? In the following example do we need *is* or *are*?

> I want you to know how much your effort, time, and work are/is appreciated.

I want you to know how much your effort, time, and work are/is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You have three (uncountable) items. Any one, by itself, would take **is**:

> I want you to know how much your **effort is** appreciated.
>
> I want you to know how much your **time is** appreciated.
>
> I want you to know how much your **work is** appreciated.

Joining them with **or** would also take an **is** (but would not make sense).

Joining them with an **and** means that *these three things **are** appreciated*

> I want you to know how much your **effort, time, and work** **are** appreciated.